# How do we create getters/setters in APEX, and why do we need {get; set;}?

Tags: apex

In trying to create getters and setters for my APEX classes, I am creating standard methods such as:

```
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

But, I noted that APEX supports C#-like shorthand, i.e. `{get; set;}`. When attempting to use this shorthand - anticipating it will create the `getName` method automatically - I receive an error that the method does not exist.

I assume that the shorthand was not made to support this type of usage, but it does then beg the question: what is its purpose? I also noted that it is required that the variable be declared `public`. Again, if the variable is already made accessible from outside the class, defining a getter and setter would seem redundant.

Comment: In e.g. an Apex test just reference the property by its name; the get/set logic will still execute. It's the Visualforce parser that will accept either the get/set shortcut or an explicitly coded get or set method.